# overwrite a method in a jdbc third party jar

Tags: java, reflection

I want to access my database through ebean. My database is a Gupta SQLBase 11.5 (don't wonder if you don't know it). The problem is that the guys at gupta are very lazy. So their implementation of java.sql.DatabaseMetaData.getDatabaseMajorVersion throws an SqlException: unsupported method. Is it possible to overwrite that method in my application so that it just returns 11? I already tried to implement my own jdbc.gupta.sqlbase.SqlbaseDatabaseMetaData class with this method which indeed works but I'm not able to implement all methods the interface needs. That is why all selects I do through ebean returns null. So I only need to overwrite the getDatabaseMajorVersion method. IMHO there is no opinion to implement a subclass which just extends the gupta class cause my class would never be taken.

thanks for every advise you can give.
best regards, Marco

Comment: what functionality requires `getDatabaseMajorVersion()` to return a value?

Comment: the initialize process of ebean calls this method.

Comment: have you tried writing a wrapper for the class which delegates to the real instance in every method but getDatabaseMajorVersion()?

Comment: I am not sure how this is possible if I implement a wrapper with the same name in the same package!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a wrapper, either by using the [delegate pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern), or by [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) (reflection). You will need to intercept any invocation of the "overriden" methods, and delegate the others to the underlying object.

For convenience, you could also write a wrapper for `Connection`, and override `Connection.getMetaData()`, which should return an instance of your wrapper.

If you want to go fancy, you may also register an implementation of [`Driver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Driver.html) that rewrites the connection URL and returns an instance of your `Connection`.

Comment: thank you very much. I tried the proxy solution and it works like a charm.

Comment: @Marco Facing similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649981/hive-driver-throws-method-not-supported-exception. Can you provide your implementation?